# The group generated by a and b is the same as the group generated by ab and b

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a group G generated by two elements a and b, both in G with order 2, show that the group generated by a & b is the same as the group generated by ab & b.

Would I have to somehow show they're identical through finding the identities and comparing?

Comment: Simply show that a and b are words in ab and b, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this statement holds in full generality.

Then, you can express both $ab$ and $b$ using the building blocks $a$ and $b$ (and their inverses). 
This implies the containment of the generated subgroups $\langle ab,b\rangle\subseteq \langle a,b\rangle$.

And conversely, you can express both $a$ and $b$ using the building blocks $ab$ and $b$ (and their inverses), so that $\langle a,b\rangle\subseteq \langle ab,b\rangle$.

> We have $a=(ab)\cdot b^{-1}$.

Comment: You don't even need $b$ to have finite order: $(ab) \cdot b^{-1} \in \langle ab, b \rangle$.  (Of course, the argument as given would be useful if you were working with monoids or semigroups.)

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I see more monoids than groups nowadays, indeed : )